# Connect to Postgres in Laravel using Docker containers

Tags: laravel, postgresql, docker

I have an issue to connect to Postgres container from Laravel.

They are on the same host created as separated Docker containers.

Here is YML:

```
version: '3'
services:

  # The Application
  app:
    env_file: .env
    container_name: "laravel"
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=${DB_PORT}"
      - "DB_HOST=${DB_HOST}"
      - "DB_USER=${DB_USER}"
      - "DB_PASS=${DB_PASS}"
      - "DB_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE}"
      - "DB_SCHEMA=${DB_SCHEMA}"
    restart: 'always'
  # The Web Server
  web:
    container_name: "nginx"
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    restart: 'always'
  # The Database
  pgsql:
    image: postgres:10.1
    container_name: "baza"
    environment:
      - 'DB_USER=${DB_USER}'
      - 'DB_PASS=${DB_PASS}'
    volumes:
      - '${DB_VOLUME_LOCATION}:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
    ports:
      - "${DB_PORT}:${PGSQL_CONTAINER_PORT}"
    restart: 'always'
```

Here `.env` variables for Laravel 5:

```
# postgres
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=6666
DB_DATABASE=postgres
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASS=postgres
PGSQL_CONTAINER_PORT=5432
```

docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                 NAMES
2b8e667bcb08        postgres:10.1           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 seconds ago       Up 1 second         0.0.0.0:6666->5432/tcp                baza
58f1573bf016        laraveldockerized_app   "php-fpm"                4 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        9000/tcp                              laravel
8a24bd5073a8        laraveldockerized_web   "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   4 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds        443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp         nginx
```

I'm able to connect to postgres from outside using DataGrip and:

- host: localhost
- port: 6666
- user: postgres
- pass: postgres

But when I try to connect with Laravel I'm getting following error:

> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused Is
> the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
> TCP/IP connections on port 6666? could not connect to server: Cannot
> assign requested address Is the server running on host "localhost"
> (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 6666? (SQL: select *
> from "dokuments")

I tried to change DB_HOST in .env to:

- baza
- pgsql
- 127.0.0.1
- 0.0.0.0

but nothing of above works.

Comment: Only God can connect Laravel app to Postgresql.

Comment: @ShahidKarimi I am God.

Comment: @Qumber God, please grant me this one. Connect postgres to Laravel in a docker container. I ask nothing more. Amen.

Comment: @JohnO What issue are you facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add change name of databae

```
environment:
      - 'DB_USER=${DB_USER}'
      - 'DB_PASS=${DB_PASS}'
      # - 'DB_NAME=${DB_NAME}'
-------------------------------
DB_HOST=pgsql
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=postgres
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASS=postgres
```

Comment: I can't use DB_PORT=5432 because another postgres instance is running on that port. I left it at 6666 and I did as you said I added DB_NAME to env variables and to YML file. I tried with DB_HOST=pgsql and DB_HOST=baza ( it is container name ). It doesn't work. 

SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not translate host name "baza" to address: Name or service not known (SQL: select * from "dokuments")

Comment: You env does need to use 5432, the 6666 port is on your local network, the containers will communicate on 5432.

Answer (score 1):

You should get the ip of Postgres container by using following command.

```
docker inspect -f '{{.Name}} - {{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $(docker ps -aq)
```

Then Replace the Ip of Postgres container in your Laravel .env as host.

Comment: Tnx buddy, this answer help me.